# ZCash z-addr timestamp missing in transaction history

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, zcash

I am calling the following command to get transaction history

```
zcash-cli z_listreceivedbyaddress "ztMTTKVFt3YFzJDn4ADhox9q7gbyUekKsCgzWSfNkqCPVbrstDXNTmy5zHHWiKQcrMUMQZqiTE2pdGE7kXiox73EFGNnYnb"
```

And I am getting the following response

```
[
  {
    "txid": "f419d49685ba77099f39094ff52ef81d082eac74f4e0a2cdead9b3a51b4b243c",
    "amount": 1.00000000,
    "memo": "5468616e6b7320"
  }
]
```

Now I need to get an additional field like timestamp. Is there any public api for zcash z-addr from where I can get full transaction history including timestamp?

Please help me.